# how to create treafik2 jwtSource in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am reading the traefik 2 document and found before doing the jwt authorize, we should create jwt source, this is the official document https://doc.traefik.io/traefik-enterprise/middlewares/jwt/ and this is the yaml define:

```
authSources:
  jwtSource:
    jwt:
      signingSecret: super-secret
```

but I still did not figure out how to create a authSources, is this a standalone type or configmap? what should I do to create the authSources? I have tried to create it but failed:

```
error: error validating "/private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/fda5f3ce56950ba8494c40d4be25fb1a/resource.yaml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: Seems to be you are using `signingSecret` directly without mentioning its API version and Kind. You need to use the signingSecret as a secret in the config map and also define the Traefik ForwardAuth Middleware in the same namespace of the server as per this [Traefik middleware - Forward authentication blog](https://dev.to/lenra/traefik-middleware-forward-authentication-1nc1) authored by Alienor.

Comment: You also need to install the [traefik-jwt-plugin](https://github.com/team-carepay/traefik-jwt-plugin) mentioned in this gitlink by eshepelyuk and also follow the examples mentioned in the plugin gitlink.

Comment: is this helped  to resolve your issue? let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: I take a long time to figure out, seems auth source only support by traefik enterprise. the forward auth middleware did not need to install plugin, it supported internal. @HemanthKumar it is different. your comment are helpful. the traefik products are too much right now to figure out.